# how to delete all ms access tables except for a defined list

Tags: database

There are tables I like to keep and tables I need to delete at a click of a button in MS Access 2010 through the form view. The database has 5 tables (excluding system tables and other Microsoft developed tables). Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 and Table5. I need to keep Table1 and Table2 but with the click of the button in form view, fire an event that will remove Table3, Table4 and Table5.
I do not wish to have the system tables and others removed. What is the VBA code for this?

Answer (score 0):

CurrentDb.Execute "DROP TABLE [table name]"

Are your tables truly named Table1, Table2, etc.?

Why do you need to do this? Do not advise implementing code that routinely modifies db structure.

Comment: thanks.I get your advice. What I'm performing clearly violates the principles of database design but the database itself never followed strict database design principles to begin with so the table names Table1, Table2, etc are just hypothetical objects that were created to support of views to certain tables because MS ACCESS does not have the proper Object Oriented Language features such as Oracle.

Comment: Still don't understand why the need to programmatically delete tables. Are you programmatically creating them as well? Regardless, hope you have enough information to proceed.